# How to use session created in JAVA in angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, session

I use the following code to create session in **JAVA**

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("popMSG","Service removed successfully");
```

Or in case f error

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("popMSGF","Oops something went wrong!");
```

I need to get this session in my **AngularJS function**, in the following code.

```
msg(value_from_angularJS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create another end point in your backend code for client to get information. For example:

```
public String getMessage() {
   //This is spring code may be different from your code.
   HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest(); // This is spring code may be different with your code.
   return request.getSession().getAttribute("popMSGF");
}
```

Comment: I am using spring. I am able to create and use sessions in java. But how can I access directly from AngularJS, like we do in JSTL or jsp

Comment: Well, JSTL or JSP work on your backend while AngularJS work on your client site. Thus there is no way to direct access to Session object in your server unless provided them an endpoint.

Comment: Ohk. Currently, I tried using a variable to store data and sent them to page sending back session value only and receive them and use that data using angular.

Answer (score -3):

```
sessionStorage.getItem("popMSGF")
```

Comment: sessionStorage and HttpSession are two different things.